# Get dynamic column data(i.e. without getter setter in action classes) in struts action classes

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am new in struts development.

I had created a project in which i have requirement to create a dynamically N number of fields. so it's bean/pojo will not be available.

I have to take input for these dynamic fields in jsp and retrieve those fields in struts2 action classes.

How can i take data of dynamically created table's fields in struts2 action classes.

**example-:**
user will create action.
one action have many goals and user can define 1 to n measures for goal.
I'll create a form to take input for these measures using jsp.
i want all form data of measures in action classes.
so i don't have getter & setter.

Any suggetion will be helpful, Thanks

Comment: is fields name are pre-define or dynamic ?

Comment: fields are dynamic. while creating goals user can define n-number of measures. i'll take these measure name from db and create a jsp page for input of these measure after submitting form i have to accept data in action class.

Comment: it means that your have your fields name in DB and from the basis of user input fields are display ?

Comment: yes, i am displaying input fields from db and i have to take input for these fields in action classes.

Comment: what you want to do with this value on server side or in action class ?

Comment: I want to get and add these data in database for reference of selected measures table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Read all request parameter send from client side to server side you can get it by using `ServletRequest.getParameterMap()`

For Example :

```
Map<String, String[]> requestParams = request.getParameterMap();
```

By this you got the all your form parameters in key-value pair.
Iterate this Map and get your parameter value.

I not aware of your table structure in which you want to insert your value.

Comment: but how i ll get request object in action class??

Comment: by `HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest() ;`